# Penthao Kettle: How to apply query timeout in my transformation

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have designed a transformation that will fetch data using table input from sql server(remote machine)

everything works fine till connection is there.

But if the query is in progress and somehow your machine got disconnected from LAN than in that case kettle shows query execution is in process even after 1 hour.

Ideally there should be some query time out in the kettle to avoid this never ending process.

Answer (score 0):

You can set connection parameters:-
[image]
And get help to set connection parameter from help. Like for SQLSERVER , use this link http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat